# Icons showing as garbage symbols on refresh of page

Tags: html, user-interface, icons

I am using some custom icons in my application, as show below.

[image: Image of actual icons]

However when I refresh the page, or sometimes on some other action, the icons change to these garbage symbols. This happens randomly. Is there any permanent solution for this?

[image: Image of garbage icons]

Here is a bit of the sample code where these icon classes are used. These are custom icons and the icon.css is added to the assets folder.

````
    [ngClass]="{'disable':disableDeleteIcon()}" (click)="deleteContact()"></span>

<span class="icon-edit grid-renderer-edit-icon" title="Edit"
    *ngIf="params.colDef.headerName == 'Action' && !params.isDeletedRecords" [ngClass]="{'disable':disableEditIcon()}"
    (click)="editContact()"></span>

<span class="icon-refresh grid-renderer-restore-icon" title="Restore"
    *ngIf="params.colDef.headerName == 'Action' && params.isDeletedRecords" (click)="restoreContact()"></span>```
````

Comment: Share Your Code

Comment: @RushabhGandhi Just added the extra info to the question!